# Is the time complexity/Big O of this function a constant?

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

is the time complexity of this program O(1)?

```
f1(int n){
  int temp = n;
  while (temp /= 2))
  {
    len++; result+=m;
  }
}
```

and if we change int temp to double temp, does the time complexity change as well, or it will remain constant?

```
f2(int n){
  double temp = (double)n;
  while (temp /= 2))
  {
    len++; result+=m;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Input is halved each time, would that not be `O(log n)`?

Comment: and of course there will be more iterations with `double`. Not sure about the complexity though. comparing floats to 0 isn't a good idea.

Comment: I meant `O(log n)` sorry!

Comment: my fingers wanted it to be `O(n)`. They had the `n` right :)

Comment: The double case is *theoretically* undefined, as it should loop forever. Yet not sure how it will behave

Comment: It won't loop forever. after a while, underflow will make the value 0.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I said *theoretically*. Probably implementation defined.

Comment: it would loop forever if double type had infinite bytes of precision

Comment: it becomes `O(n)` because you need a given number of divisions by 2 to reach 0 (implementation defined, yes)

Comment: I think it's O(FP precision), which is a constant for any given FP representation, so it's O(1).

Comment: it's `O(log n)` (until it reaches 1) then it's fixed.

Comment: @Barmar This reasoning is invalid in my eyes, since every computation on a real computer has an upper bound depending on its resources or  is infinite (busy beaver theorem), so you could reason that everything is O(1) there

Comment: @Ctx Good point. In this case, dividing by 2 either subtracts 1 from the exponent, or shifts the mantissa when the minimum exponent is reached. So it's O(log(n) + number of significant digits in n)

Comment: @Ctx However, this question is specifically about a particular representation, not a about abstract algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for the integer part is `O(log n)` because the value is halved each time.

The double version starts the same way, except that when the value reaches 1 or close to 1, it doesn't stop and divides until underflow makes it 0. At this point, the number of divisions is fixed.

I've made a small empirically calibrated program which tries to predict the number of loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void f2(int n){
  int len=0;
  double temp = (double)n;
  while (temp /= 2)
  {
    len++; 
  }
  // 1.53 is an empiric constant, maybe it could be theorically computed
  // it was just to make the numbers match
  printf("%d %lf\n",len,log(n)*1.53+1074);
}
int main()
{

    f2(100000000);
    f2(10000000);
    f2(1000000);
    f2(10000);
    f2(100);
    f2(1);

}
```

I get:

```
1101 1102.183642
1097 1098.660686
1094 1095.137731
1087 1088.091821
1081 1081.045910
1074 1074.000000
```

So the complexity is `O(log n)` plus an incompressible number of iterations, depending on the machine.

(my apologies for the empiric aspect of my answer, I'm not a floating point expert)

Comment: Im watching you

Answer (score 2):

For an algorithm to have constant time-complexity, its runtime should stay constant as the number of inputs, `n`, grows. If your function on `n = 1` and `n = 1000000` takes different amounts of time to run, your function is not `O(1)`, i.e. it doesn't have a constant time complexity.

Let's calculate how many steps the first function takes to terminate:

n/2<sup>x</sup> = 1 ⇒ x = log(n)

For the second, however, it will theoretically keep dividing `n` by 2 forever, but in reality, it will terminate after some `log(n) + c` steps, in which case the constant will be omitted, and the complexity is going to be `log(n)` again.